# How to keep a 30 day schedule script running with schedule

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

How do I close the terminal but keep a scheduled script running? It works for seconds, minutes with the terminal opened but terminates when the terminal is closed. Is there a way of working around it?

```py
from schedule import every, repeat, run_pending
import time

@repeat(every(30).days.at("11:30"))
def auto_run_task():
    """Auto run task in every 30days to update CSV files."""
    print("Auto run task activated.")
    update_csv_file()
    print("file updated successfully")

while True:
    run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on Linux, do `nohup python myscript.py &`.  The purpose of the `nohup` command is to make the script a daemon so it detaches from the terminal.

Comment: Hi Tim! thanks for your time to answer me, and how do I **kill** the terminal when I want to?

Comment: You mean, "how do I kill the script when I want to?"   When you enter that command, it will give you a process id ("`[1] 262988`"), or you do `ps af` to look up all of your current processed.  You do `kill 262988` to kill that process.